# Close opened window after X sec with javascript (print a div)

Tags: javascript

I want to print a div with javascript. Here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintDiv() {
            var divContents = document.getElementById("dvContents").innerHTML;
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=200,width=400');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Nyomtatás</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            self.close();
            printWindow.print();
        }
</script>
```

This code open the div content in a new window and start to print. I want to close this windows with *printWindow.document.close();* but it doesn't close. Do you have idea how can I close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printWindow.close()` instead of `printWindow.document.close()` and it will close the window.

https://jsfiddle.net/qba6h5up/1/

This jsfiddle opens and closes a window after a set amount of milliseconds (you will see it if you have popups enabled).

Modify `timeToCloseWindow` variable to adjust the time of the window closing, or just add milliseconds directly.